# Add custom block in a Wordpress block theme(Not with the plugin)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, gutenberg-blocks

Basically I want to develop a wordpress block theme.For easy to customize I want  to add some custom block in my theme.But I don't want to create a plugin for this.Custom block will be inside my theme.When someone install my theme he will get those custom block built in with my theme.How can I achive it and how can I organize my folder structure as well??

Comment: No new update for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to create a **src** folder inside your theme then put your block folders there (shown structure below).

Folder Structure may be:

-- theme folder
--> src
--> block-folder > block files(edit.js, index.js, save.js etc.)

For block files:

Now it's time to install `wp-scripts` package to work with wp blocks. For that, Update your **package.json** file adding below lines. then in terminal go to the theme folder and command '**npm install**' it will install all your dependencies packages then give the '**npm start**' command.

```
{
"main": "build/index.js",
"scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build",
    "format": "wp-scripts format",
    "lint:css": "wp-scripts lint-style",
    "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js",
    "packages-update": "wp-scripts packages-update",
    "plugin-zip": "wp-scripts plugin-zip",
    "start": "wp-scripts start"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^23.4.0"
}
}
```

Note: You need to register block via `register_block_type` function for PHP way or `registerBlockType` for JS way. Otherwise, above code won't work. Above codes will create your files only.

Answer (score 8):

I just had to do the same: Register a custom block inside of my theme.

### Create block inside of `src/blocks`

First, I created the block inside `src/blocks` using `npx @wordpress/create-block my-block`. The block is now located in `{theme}/src/blocks/my-block`.

### Build the block

Then, I built the block using `npm run build`.

### Register `block.json` from the build folder

Lastly, I registered the block using the `block.json` metadata file of the *build*:

**functions.php**

```php
function register_my_block()
{
    register_block_type( dirname(__FILE__) . '/src/blocks/my-block/build/block.json' );
}
add_action('init', 'register_my_block');
```

Comment: I was wondering where this is located in the docs.  For now it [can be found here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/core-concepts/theme-structure/#optional-folders).  e.g. "'inc'...This folder may also be seen named as includes, src, and more"